# batch file to show attributes of a series of similarly-named files

Tags: batch-file

I haven't done anything with batch files in 10 years but I find myself needing to list the filesize of a bunch of files, named CG100.mpg though CG999.mpg

There must be a way to get a batch file to look at a series of similarly named files one by one, using a FOR loop?

Comment: Can you only use a batch file?  What about Python or Perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely there is a simple way to get your result using FOR - read about the FOR loop expansion modifiers at the end of the help - type `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` from the command line.

You don't even need a batch file. This one liner will do exactly what you want on the command line:

```
for /l %N in (100 1 999) do @for %F in (GC%N.mpg) do @if exist %F echo %F size = %~zF
```

Change all the `%` to `%%` if you use the command within a batch file.

The command is even simpler if you just want to list the size of all files that match the pattern `GC*.mpg`:

```
for %F in (GC*.mpg) do @echo %F size = %~zF
```

Comment: The first answer you gave is exactly what I would have done if I could have remembered how to use a variable as part of a filename. Your second answer is wonderfully compact. Thanks!

Comment: @RichHarrison - Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the check box near the upper left hand corner of the answer if your question has been answered to your satisfaction. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 points for taking the time to accept, and awards the answer poster 15 points. Only 1 answer can be accepted. Once you amass 15 points you will have the privilege to up vote any answer that you find useful, whether it be an answer to your question, or any answer you find on the site. You can vote up multiple answers to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to utilize Python then the following would work:

```
from os.path import getsize

results = [('CG%d.mpg = ' % i) + str(getsize('CG%d.mpg' % i)) for i in range(100, 999)]

print results
```

Otherwise for batch files you could use [FORFILES](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html):

```
Select a file (or set of files) and execute a command on each file. Batch processing.

Syntax
      FORFILES [/p Path] [/m Mask] [/s] [/c Command] [/d [+ | -] {dd/MM/yyyy | dd}]   

Key    /p Path      The Path to search  (default=current folder)

   /s           Recurse into sub-folders

   /C command   The command to execute for each file.
                Wrap the command string in double quotes.
                Default = "cmd /c echo @file"

                The Command variables listed below can also be used in the
                command string.

   /D date      Select files with a last modified date greater than or

                equal to (+), or less than or equal to (-),
                the specified date using the "dd/MM/yyyy" format;

   /D + dd      Select files with a last modified date greater than or
                equal to the current date plus "dd" days. (in the future)

   /D - dd      Select files with a last modified date less than or
                equal to the current date minus "dd" days. (in the past)

                A valid "dd" number of days can be any number in
                the range of 0 to 32768.   (89 years)
                "+" is taken as default sign if not specified.

   Command Variables:
      @file    The name of the file.
      @fname   The file name without extension.                
      @ext     Only the extension of the file.                  
      @path    Full path of the file.
      @relpath Relative path of the file.          
      @isdir   Returns "TRUE" if a file type is a directory,
               and "FALSE" for files.
      @fsize   Size of the file in bytes.
      @fdate   Last modified date of the file.
      @ftime   Last modified time of the file.
```

Comment: FORFILES looks very promising and I was not aware that it existed, so thanks for that. I love the compact look of the Python code but I haven't learned or installed Python yet.